# How to get a singly linked list to sort hex numbers

Tags: java

Hi I have this code which will sort a list of strings in order, I can also sort a array into ascending too as there are plenty of tutorials to help me. The problem I have is to sort numbers with letters attached. Is this possible? Here's what I have so far.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LinkedList2 {
public static class Node {
    public String value;
    public Node next;
}

static File dataInpt;
static Scanner inFile;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    inFile = new Scanner("20\r\n" + "38\r\n" + "5c\r\n" + "2b\r\n" + "54\r\n" + "63\r\n" + "53\r\n" + "43\r\n" + "40\r\n"
            + "14\r\n" + "2a\r\n" + "42\r\n" + "63\r\n" + "63\r\n" + "5c\r\n" + "4c\r\n");
    Node first = insertInOrder();
    printList(first);
}

public static Node getNode(String element) {
    Node temp = new Node();
    temp.value = element;
    temp.next = null;
    return temp;
}

public static void printList(Node head) {
    Node ptr; // not pointing anywhere
    for (ptr = head; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.next) {
        System.out.println(ptr.value);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static Node insertInOrder() {
    Node current = getNode(inFile.next());
    Node first = current, last = current;
    while (inFile.hasNext()) {
        if (first != null && current.value.compareTo(first.value) < 0) {
            current.next = first;
            first = current;
        } else if (last != null && current.value.compareTo(last.value) > 0) {
            last.next = current;
            last = current;
        } else {
            Node temp = first;
            while (current.value.compareTo(temp.value) < 0) {
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            current.next = temp.next;
            temp.next = current;
        }
        current = getNode(inFile.next());
    }
    return first;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to sort any kind of `Comparable` elements.

If you are using a `String` as value it will be sorted using the natural order of strings. If you need a different comparison policy you need to write your `Comparator` and use it to compare the values instead of compare them directly

```
public static Node insertInOrder(Comparator<String> comparator) {
    Node current = getNode(inFile.next());
    Node first = current, last = current;
    while (inFile.hasNext()) {
        if (first != null && comparator.compare(current.value, first.value) < 0) {
            current.next = first;
            first = current;
        } else if (last != null && comparator.compare(current.value, last.value) > 0) {
            last.next = current;
            last = current;
        } else {
            Node temp = first;
            while (comparator.compare(current.value, temp.value) < 0){
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            current.next = temp.next;
            temp.next = current;
        }
        current = getNode(inFile.next());
    }
    return first;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but get this exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: LinkedList2.insertInOrder
 at LinkedList2.main(LinkedList2.java:29)
Java Result: 1`

Comment: There were problems on paranthesis closures. Sorry I didn't tried to compile it. Try again.

Comment: I'm still getting an exception on line 29 saying method insertInOrder in class LinkedList2 cannot be applied to given types; required: Comparator<String> found: no arguments reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to store an additional data `int` data item corresponding to `String value` using below method of `Integer` class,

```
public static int parseInt(String s,int radix) throws NumberFormatException
```

where radix=16. Then you can sort it as normal integer ( base 10 ).

You need to change your `Node`  class to have `int` in place of `String`

```
public static class Node {
    public int value;
    public Node next;
}
```

then in your `getNode(String element)` method , you perform **HEX String** to `int` conversion,

```
    public static Node getNode(String element) {
        Node temp = new Node();
        try{

temp.value = Integer.parseInt(element,16);
}catch(NumberFormatException ex){
ex.printStackTrace();
}
        temp.next = null;
        return temp;
    }
```

Now you edit your `insertInOrder()` method to do comparison as simple integers , > , < , == etc instead of `value.compareTo`

Comment: how would i implement this?

Comment: I have revised my answer to show as how to achieve this. You can follow Davide Lorenzo MARINO's advice to write a separate comparator to have more robust code. Ask specific questions on your attempts if you face any issues.